# How to loop inside a nd.array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I have a N Dimensional array = X, I want to check each value in X if it is greater than 0.35 . I write as :-

```
for number in X:
    if (.35> number):  # Here error occurs
        print (enumerate(number))
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I want to save the index of each value in X that is less than 0.35 in a list

Comment: You can use [`numpy.nd.array.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), but you probable want to use John Zwinck's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with NumPy you must always strive to operate in vector space.  That means not writing `for` loops, nor `in`, etc.

For your present case, you can do this:

```
print(X[X < 0.35])
```

This will be massively faster than writing a loop.  If you have to have them print on separate lines, you can:

```
values = X[X < 0.35]
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to know the index number at which the value is less than 0.35 and want to generate a list of all these index, How to do that ? (if you could let me know)

Comment: To generate a list of indexes use `np.nonzero(X < 0.35)`

Comment: @A.wadhawan, what you are looking for is numpy.where https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html